# Fork and pipe behavior

Tags: c, shell, unix, posix

In main I call another method (ex go_pipe) to process the pipe command in shell unix.        Inside the method,

```
fork()
if child:
    pipe and fork(), and do the work to process the command
if parent
    wait for child and then print the prompt for the next command
```

Somehow when I test the program with `ls | wc`, it works fine but it print the prompt before the output of this command. For the parent I simply use:

```
wait(NULL);
printf("sh2 ");
```

Comment: `wait()` waits for a **single** child to exit... in your example, `ls | wc` there are at least two children `ls` and `wc` (and perhaps a shell as well, if you're executing `ls | wc` that way). If you're executing the commands using a shell, `waitpid` on the shell PID will get the result you want.

Comment: To execute ls | wc, I basically split the whole thing into two sub arrays of pointers to be processed (ls and wc in this case). Then, still inside main, I pass these two to a separate method as shown above. I tried wait(pid, NULL,0) inside the parent but it still didn't work, where pid = fork() at the beginning of the method. I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to all these shell programming stuffs. Oh and btw, I used execvp to execute these commands inside the child, so my guess is it doesn't return to the calling process?

Comment: so you fork() a child which runs the commands... assuming the child exits after it has run the commands and itself wait for the commands to exit, then simply `waitpid(<pid of the child>)` in the parent. if the child does not wait for the commands, then you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks again for putting up with me... Isn't waitpid supposed to have 3 arguments? And what do you mean by "if the child does not wait for the commands", as my understanding is after fork() and pipe are executed inside the child, the children would go and execvp their own thing, and Never return to their parent (which is a child to the outter fork). This is the point where I think the issue is. I'm just wondering does that mean the outtest child get replaced, and the parent thereforce will always execute first? Idk I'm confusing myself